# object references an unsaved transient instance - trouble saving new child / grandchild references

Tags: hibernate, jpa, save, cascade, transient

I'm having cascade save problem with hibernate and am not having much luck tracing the source code.

In short, I have a three level parent/child/grandchild relationship mapped and when I save a reference to 1 parent with 2 children and each child has a handful of grandchildren then first persist is successful and everyone gets the appropriate ids:

```
Parent (id:p1)
    child1 (id:parent,c1)
        grandchild (id:child1,g1)
        grandchild (id:child1,g2)
    child2 (id:parent,c2)
        grandchild (id:child2,g1)
        grandchild (id:child2,g2)
```

If I then load the parent (eagerly) and add a new child with several of it's own new grand children, I get the unsaved transient error when I attempt to persist the changes via the parent object:

```
Parent (id:p1)
    child1 (id:parent,c1)
        grandchild1 (id:child1,g1)
        grandchild2 (id:child1,g2)
    child2 (id:parent,c2)
        grandchild3 (id:child2,g1)
        grandchild4 (id:child2,g2)
    child3 (id:<new>)
        grandchild5 (id:child3,<new>)
        grandchild6 (id:child3,<new>)
```

This is the basic, JPA style, syntax I use to save the object both times:

> rulesRepository.save(parent).

In the hibernate code I can see the code decides if the parent is transient and executes the appropriate save or merge methods.  The first pass performs a save, while the second calls merge.

Tracing the hibernate code I see where it's about to save a new grandchild, realizes it needs the parent's key (child3), and then tried to get the child's id fields. Only because the child is also new I get the unsaved transient error.

**The question is why is hibernate unable to resolve child3's key (by inspecting it's parent) as it resolves the grandchild's id during a merge, when it's clearly able to do this for a save when the entire model is transient?**

Adding to the possible problem is that the middle tier (child) is actually a JOINED subtype.  The grandchild objects are associated with all subtypes so are mapped to the discriminator class.

Here's what I have mapped:

Parent:

```
@Entity
@Transactional
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name="DS_EXTENDED_DATA_SOURCE")
public final class Rule {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="IdentityProvider")
    @GenericGenerator(name="IdentityProvider", strategy="com.teradata.tac.domain.common.IdentityProvider")
    @Column(name="Extended_Data_Source_Id", nullable=false, length=MAX_ID_LENGTH, updatable=false, insertable=true)
    private String  extendedDataSourceId;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="rule")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OrderBy("Display_X_Position_Num,Display_Y_Position_Num,Extended_Data_Source_Id")
    private List<Node<?>> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Child - Discriminator:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(NodeId.class)
@Table(name="DS_XDS_NODE")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="Xds_Node_Type_Cd")
public class Node<T extends Node<T>> extends BaseDomain<Node<T>> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="IdentityProvider")
    @GenericGenerator(name="IdentityProvider", strategy="com.teradata.tac.domain.common.IdentityProvider")
    @Column(name="Xds_Node_Id", nullable=false, length=MAX_ID_LENGTH, updatable=false, insertable=false)
    protected String xdsNodeId;

    @Column(name="Xds_Node_Type_Cd", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    protected short xdsNodeTypeCd;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="Extended_Data_Source_Id", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)
    @JsonBackReference(value="rule")
    protected Rule rule;

    // Selected Columns
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="node")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OrderBy("Display_Ord")
    protected List<SelectedColumn> selectedColumns = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Example Child-Subclass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DS_XDS_JOIN_NODE")
@DiscriminatorValue("60")
public class JoinNode extends Node<JoinNode> {

}
```

Grandchild:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SelectedColumnId.class)
@Table(name = "DS_XDS_SELECTED_COLUMN")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class SelectedColumn {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "IdentityProvider")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "IdentityProvider", strategy = "com.teradata.tac.domain.common.IdentityProvider")
    @Column(name = "Xds_Selected_Column_Id", nullable = false, length = MAX_ID_LENGTH, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    protected String xdsSelectedColumnId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "Extended_Data_Source_Id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "Xds_Node_Id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false) })
    protected Node<?> node;
}
```

All of the IdClasses used have similar layouts:

```
public class NodeId {

    private Rule   rule;           // Parent object reference
    private String xdsNodeId;      // local instance id (not guaranteed to be unique)

    public NodeId() {}

    public NodeId(Rule rule, String xdsNodeId) {
        this.rule = rule;
        this.xdsNodeId = xdsNodeId;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.xdsNodeId;
    }

    public Rule getRule() {
        return this.rule;
    }
}
```

I've omitted overloaded equals and hashcode methods but essentially they all match the key fields.

The best I've managed to trace the root cause to is this method: AbstractEntityPersister:4480

> public boolean canExtractIdOutOfEntity() {
>        return hasIdentifierProperty() || hasEmbeddedCompositeIdentifier() || hasIdentifierMapper();
>      }

This is where hibernate (1.5.2.RELEASE) has determined that the grandchild being saved is transient and needs it's id to be pulled from it's parent (child3).  As it goes in search of the id it executes the function above and all of the reference methods return null, resulting in the call returning false.  At this point the exception is thrown

Any insight into what i might be doing wrong would be appreciated, and a solution would be very welcome.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others, I'll answer my own question with how I managed to solve the problem.

The basic problem was that I was relying on the @ManyToOne mapping relationships to provide the parent ids into the child objects.  In doing so I wasn't directly mapping the parent id fields into the children.

While this might work for a two level hierarchy, what it appears to mean is that any subsequent levels below this see a dependency on the parent id in the 2nd level child, but don't see an explicit column to map to.  I feel like is a bug, but I'm not confident enough in my understanding to make that assumption.

Anyway, to solve the issue I performed the following three changes:

1) I mapped all parent @Id columns directly into each child (every level subsequently added more and more keys).  Only the field and @Column aspects were copied over.

2) The @ManyToOne parent mappings in each child were NOT marked as IDs

3) I added an @PrePersist mapping to each child to pull the parent id(s) from the @ManyToOne mapped parent object and copy the values into the mapped fields.

All along I felt like I needed to map the columns explicitly, but didn't know how I would get the ids from the parents populated.  Only when I put two and two together did I realize that a non-id @ManyToOne mapping combined with a @PrePersist could accomplish this.

I suspect @MapsId might have the same affect as the logic in the @PrePersist code block so will have to experiment, but for now... It works.

Hope this helps someone someday...